# Unable to find my.ini file on my computer

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to set `lower_case_table_names=2` in MySQL so that I can use upper case characters for defining column names in tables.

Most answers on stack overflow have asked to add lower_case_table_names=2 in "my.ini" file. 
I'm not able to find this file on my computer.

edit- There is no ProgramData folder in C drive.

Answer (score 1):

File with extension **.ini** remains hidden. Type **C:\ProgramData** in the *address bar*. It should open the **ProgramData** directory/folder.

Answer (score 0):

It is hidden from view.

But you can change it

by changing the settings

> Under Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives, and then select OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
D:\TEMP>wmic service Mysql80 get Pathname
PathName
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="D:\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```

The default for **Mysql80** point, on my computer, to: D:\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini.

If you do not know the exact name of the service, you can also do:

```
wmic service get Pathname | findstr /i mysql
```

this will display (again, on my computer):

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="D:\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```